# is KVR16N11/4 and KVR16N11/8 are compatible to each other?

Tags: memory

I have this 2 ram which are the KVR16N11/4 and KVR16N11/8.
I just wanted to confirm if I can use them both in 1 pc at the same time.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Both cards have identical characteristics.

Whether this will work or not depends solely on your motherboard.
You will need to try to find out what it can accept, by simply putting the cards in.

Nothing bad can come from such a test, and it can easily be undone if it doesn't work.